# How Do I Use an Import Function in a Vue 3 Template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In a Vue 3 project, I have the following setup. There is a separate `stuff.ts` file with some helper functions in it and I want to use it in my template.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import { doSomething } from '@/helpers/stuff.ts'
  
  export default defineComponent({
    setup(){
      onMounted(() => console.log(doSomething)) //<-- logs here okay
    }
  })
</script>

<template>
  <!-- ERROR: doSomething is not a function -->
  <a href="#do" @click="doSomething()">Do Something</a>
</template>
```

As far as I can tell, the function is properly imported and it's defined when I log it in `onMounted()`.

But when I click the link and try to `doSomething()` from the template, it says the function isn't defined. I'm new to Vue 3, but I imagine I have to do something to prep the function and make it available.

How can I make an imported function available to my template? Do I have to call a component method instead and use `doSomething` inside that?

Comment: Expose it to the tmpl via data / methods / computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to just "forward" it via the return of your setup function

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import { doSomething } from '@/helpers/stuff.ts'
  
  export default defineComponent({
    setup(){
      onMounted(() => console.log(doSomething)) //<-- logs here okay
      return { doSomething }
    }
  })
</script>

<template>
  <!-- ERROR: doSomething is not a function -->
  <a href="#do" @click="doSomething()">Do Something</a>
</template>
```

Comment: How do you do this if you use <script setup> instead?

Answer (score 4):

Return from the setup hook :

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import { doSomething } from '@/helpers/stuff.ts'
  
  export default defineComponent({
    setup(){
      onMounted(() => console.log(doSomething)) 

   return {doSomething}
    }
  })
</script>

<template>
 
  <a href="#do" @click="doSomething()">Do Something</a>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who **do not use** the `Composition API - Setup()` hook You can do the following:

```
<template>
  <a href="#do" @click="doSomething()">Do Something</a>
</template>

<script>
import { doSomething } from '@/helpers/stuff.ts'
export default {

   methods: {
      doSomething,
   }
}
</script>
```